# how to remove logs in every 2 hours in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, cron

**SETUP CRON To Delete File**

how to remove logs in every 2 hours in Linux Terminal
below is my path where my log file is kept

```
/home/test/dev/sample.log
```

I want to set a cron so every 2 hours sample.log file will be delete.

can you please help me to set that cron in Linux terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0 */2 * * * <username> echo "" > /home/test/dev/sample.log
```

add in `/etc/crontab`, restart crontab service.

Or maybe it's better to use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: @Markhenry you needs to delete file, or just clear all the data from it? My cron will white `""` (empty string) in your file every 2 hours. File will not be deleted, just cleaned from all the text.

Comment: Can  you please help me how to add it on crontab steps ? Clear data will work for me

Comment: @Markhenry well, you just need to add this string to the `/etc/crontab` file and restart the service, that's all. Step by step guide you'd better to find in Google.

Comment: i went till crontab but not getting how to add i searched in google as well but got confused that why i am asking here

Comment: @Markhenry https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/ that's good faq.